# Function Template that will add all elements of any 2-D integer array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constants

I have been tasked with creating a function template that will add all elements of any 2-dimensional integer array as part of an exercise for a programming theory language course.

I have tried several methods and keep getting compiler errors that I don't understand.

1)

```
template<typename T>
T addArraysOne(T rows, T cols, T arr[][cols])
{
    T output;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            output += arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

This one errors as the parameter for the number of columns is "not a constant".

2)

```
int addArraysTwo(int rows, int cols, int** arr)
{
    int output;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            output += *arr[i*rows+j];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

This one errors when I try and call it with `addArraysTwo(5, 5, arr);` because it "does not match the function call", when "arr" is a 2 dimensional int array. I haven't found any problems particularly similar to this online. Any suggestions on how to modify these so that I do not piss off the compiler would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If someone is teaching you C++ and telling you to use raw arrays, they are teaching you to write bad C++. You've just come across *one* of the reasons why

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following program that uses **template nontype parameters**.

**Version 1**: For integer arrays

```
#include <iostream>
//a function template that takes a 2D int array by reference
template< std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
int calculateSum(const int (&arr)[N][M])
{
    int sum = 0;
    //iterate through rows and colums of the passed 2D int array
    for(std::size_t row = 0; row < N; ++row)
    {
        for(std::size_t col = 0 ; col < M; ++col)
        {
            sum+= arr[row][col];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{3,4,5}};
    std::cout<<"Sum is: "<<calculateSum(arr)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Version 2**: For array of arbitrary type

```
#include <iostream>
//a function template that takes a 2D array(with elements of type T) by reference
template< typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
T calculateSum(const T (&arr)[N][M])
{
    T sum{0};
    //iterate through rows and colums of the passed 2D T array
    for(std::size_t row = 0; row < N; ++row)
    {
        for(std::size_t col = 0 ; col < M; ++col)
        {
            sum+= arr[row][col];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    double arr[2][3] = {{1.4,2,3},{3.6,4,5.45}};
    std::cout<<"Sum is: "<<calculateSum(arr)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For-range can even be used: `for (const auto& col : arr) for (auto e : col) sum += e;` or `for (const auto& col : arr) sum += std::accumulate(std::begin(col), std::end(col), T{0});`

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah sure. You(anyone) can decide/choose according to his/her preference.

Answer (score 0):

Your first method, variable-lengthed-array only supported by c99 (and not adopted by c++ I believe?). otherwise, the length of the array must be known at compile time. And at least with c++17 and below, any parameter of array type is adjusted to the corresponding pointer type by the compiler, so it is no difference between `int f(int a[5])` and `int f(int a[])` and `int f(int* a)`。But for 2d arrays, the size of the second dimension must be known at compile time. `int f(int a[][2])` (which is equavalent to `int f(int(*a)[2])`) is OK, but `int f(int a[][])` is not.

Your second method, 2d arrays are not implicitly convertable to pointer of pointers, but pointer to 1d arrays:

```
int arr[2][3];
int **p = arr; // Error
int(*p)[3] = arr; // OK
```

so one of the solutions is just:

```
template<typename T>
T addArraysOne(T rows, T cols, T* arr)
{
    T output = 0; // NOTE: initialize to 0
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            output += arr[i*cols+j]; // NOTE: not i*rows+j
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

and called it with:

```
int arr[2][3];
addArraysOne(2, 3, &arr[0][0]);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. This was extremely helpful.